# Syncfusion Calendar

Tags: flutter, calendar, syncfusion

I am new to flutter and would like to ask for some help.

I am working on a new mobile app. The main aim of the app is to book appointments.

After some research, I found out about syncfusion calendar widget.

Do you think using that widget might help me to achieve my aim?

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbH-jFi6TM0&t=1400s&ab_channel=Syncfusion%2CInc

It helped me a lot however it does not fully cover what I want.

At the end my question is, is it possible when the user opens the syncfusion widget and clicks on a date to book an appointment?

Comment: Do you mean sync feature i.e. when you add an event to app's calendar, you want it be synced with device calendar?

Comment: For example, I have a doctor's profile page implementing the calendar. What I am trying to do is if the user book a timeslot, the appointment is to be shown in the firebase and that timeslot is to be marked as red-booked and made it unavailable for the other people. Is that make sense? Basically, my question is if this is possible using the  syncfusion calendar widget or there is another way?

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.